# Cant login on my login activity android?

Tags: android

I am using android SQLite database where I login on my first activity and then go the other activity but when I enter the username and password its shows me password and username incorrect and didn't login to my other activity. My usernames and passwords saved in assets folder by users.xml file name. here is the code

```
    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Login(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        XMLParser xmlparser = new XMLParser();
        InputStream in;
        User user;

        EditText userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_field);
        String username = userText.getText().toString();

        EditText passText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        String password = passText.getText().toString();

        if (username.matches("\\w{1,16}") && password.matches(".{1,16}")) {
            try {
                if (login(username, password)) {
                    in = getResources().getAssets().open("Users.xml");
                    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,
                            false);
                    parser.setInput(in, null);
                    parser.nextTag();

                    user = xmlparser.getUsers(parser).get(username);

                    if (user.getRole().equals("Nurse")) {
                        intent.putExtra("userKey", new Nurse(user.getName(),
                                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), this));
                    } else if (user.getRole().equals("Physician")) {
                        intent.putExtra(
                                "userKey",
                                new Physician(user.getName(), user
                                        .getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                                        this));
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    String messgage = "Username or password are incorrect";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messgage,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (NoUserFoundException e) {
                String messgage = "Username or password are incorrect";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messgage,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            String message = "Please enter a valid username or password";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public boolean login(String username, String password)
            throws NoUserFoundException {
        boolean check = false;
        FileInputStream in = null;
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "Users.xml");

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
            String pass = new XMLParser().getPass(in, username);
            if (pass.equals(password))
                check = true;
        } catch (NoUserFoundException e) {
            throw new NoUserFoundException();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return check;

    }

}
```

here is users.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <username>JohnS</userName>
        <password>123</password>
        <name>
            <fName>John</fName>
            <lName>Smith</lName>
        </name>
        <role>Nurse</role>
    </user>
    <user>
        <userName>Matt</userName>
        <password>456</password>
        <name>
            <fName>Matt</fName>
            <lName>Smith</lName>
        </name>
        <role>Physician</role>
    </user>
</users>
```

Comment: what are you getting value at  String pass have a log after that line

Comment: username and password are incorrect

Comment: no i mean to say that  if (pass.equals(password)) decides whether to login or not so what value pass have  ?.....

Comment: SQLite database != xml file

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question, I get this code from GITHUB.COM and I don't understand how to deal with this case.. just want to enter the login and password and get to my other activity

Comment: possible problem with your `XMLParser` ? you've not really given us enough information to help you. have you at least tried debugging? `Log.d` your username and password that you're getting from the xml file and see what you're actually getting

Comment: have you debugged your app?

Comment: no I didn't try that at all... just tell me how to deal with this

Comment: have a look at this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/ this is to parse xml file